# Writing Rails Templates in Pure Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have a large number of views in my Rails application that both:

- Have a consistent and repeated structure, and
- Involve the use of helpers that accept large hash inputs.

As such, I would like to write these views directly in Ruby (using a DSL/helpers that I would write).

How can I get Rails to allow me to write `.html.rb` views?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with existing solutions like Markaby, Arbre, etc? I also don't see how your bullet points necessitate writing them in Ruby; these issues seem orthogonal.

Comment: Some information for the beginning could be found here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb

Comment: @DaveNewton, try inserting large multi-line hashes into HAML.

Comment: @thomasfedb check out haml filters http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-filter

Comment: @MarianTheisen, I have. I use the `:ruby` filter. Thanks though.

Comment: @thomasfedb Try putting large multi-line hashes where they belong--not in the view.

Comment: @DaveNewton, these are API docs. The hashes represent example responses (rendered out to JSON by a helper).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an initializer with:

```
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:rb, :source.to_proc)
```

Then you can write `.html.rb` views in ruby, they should return a `String` of the desired context when executed.